# Fix div at the bottom. (Without using javascript)

Tags: javascript, html, css, layout

To try to explain my problem, I did the following code:

http://jsfiddle.net/Ridermansb/REYZ6/

The question is.

The div "Footer" **should always be glued to the bottom of the screen** (bottom: 0).
**BUT** if the div "content" grow to the point of creating a scroll bar, the div "footer" should be just below the div "content"

One should never overlap each other!

As you can see in the example, if the screen is too small the "#footer" will override "#content". This can not happen!

Thanks!

​

Comment: Are you wanting to have a sticky footer that always sticks to the bottom of the screen unless the content pushes it out of view? Or do you want for the content to stay the same height and have a scroll bar when the content gets to be too much?

Comment: I want you to push the "#footer" out when the "#content" grow. Option 1!

Comment: It has been over a week since I updated my answer and fixed my original bug. Does it not do something you need it to?

Answer (score 1):

From what I understand per your fiddle, what you want to do is impossible with **just** css.  That said, I've come up with a single line in jquery you can use to do what I think you want:

```
$('#spacer').height($("#footer > div").height());​
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Daedalus/6arBM/2/)

Non jquery code:

```
document.getElementById('spacer').style.height = document.getElementById('​​​footer-inner').offsetHeight + "px";​​​​​
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Daedalus/6arBM/3/)

Both snippets however require a slight change to your HTML structure; they both add in a `spacer` div that pushes up the content out from under the `footer` div.  The second snippet however requires you give your footer's inner div an id as well.

Answer (score 1):

```
.container {
    position: relative;
}
.container .glued_bottom {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    height: 20px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

few ways to tackle the footer layouts

using percentage heights can work in some cases

```
html, body { height:100%;}
#header {height:10%; }
#content { height:80%; }
#footer { height:10%;}
```

Appreciate it might not fit for the content of your site, but worth a look as css only option.

Another is the use of background css elements , color your page to be your footer color ( lets say green )

and set the header and content elements to be, say, white for eg purposes

```
body { background-color:green; }
#header { background-color:white; }
#content { background-color:white; }
```

... Couple of non Javascript ideas to play with possibly

Yes, fixed or abs positioning will cause the overlaps without adding some Javascript to keep watch and make repositioning alterations.

Hope helps a little

Comment: The size of the "#footer" should be fixed. I see that the only option is to use JS. Thanks.

Comment: Unless there is something I do not understand from what you are wanting, it does not require JS, and my answer should work for you.

Comment: Josh, the answer only offers a couple of css routes to try, it does not contain javascript

Comment: @Rob I was answering Riderman de Sousa Barbosa's comment on your question.

Answer (score 0):

Via [this sticky footer tutorial](http://jsfiddle.net/REYZ6/19/). The following code should be all you need to create a sticky footer.

```
* {
    margin: 0;
}
html, body {
    height: 100%;
}
.wrapper {
    min-height: 100%;
    height: auto !important;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto -142px; /* the bottom margin is the negative value of the footer's height */
}
.footer, .push {
    height: 142px; /* .push must be the same height as .footer */
}

/*

Sticky Footer by Ryan Fait
http://ryanfait.com/

*/
```

In your case, you were missing pretty much all of the above css except for the 100% height on the html and body. I have updated your jsfiddle.

[Live DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/REYZ6/19/)

Comment: The OP wanted the footer to remain in a position similar to, if not exactly the same as `position: fixed;`

Comment: I'll check your demo in IE and Firefox, but so far, it doesn't stay at the bottom of the screen; you have to scroll down to reach it.  Tested in Chrome.

Just tested it in IE and Firefox, same thing.

Comment: No, it isn't.  Judging by the demo the OP offered himself, he wants the div to remain in a fixed position, but doesn't want it to overlap the content under it should it increase in size; in essence, he wants the margin of the bottom portion of the screen to be equal to if not slightly more than the height of the fixed position div.

Comment: Note, he said the footer should always be glued to the bottom of the screen unless the content pushes it down. In his example the content is longer than the screen; therefore, the footer should be pushed down. That is exactly what my demo does. The footer is pushed out of view because the content is too long. The OP will just have to be more descriptive if he really wants the help.

Comment: "#footer" is always invisible (even with the #content is small) and this should not happen. http://i.imgur.com/9lZBj.png   He must always be aligned with "bottom: 0" on the monitor. But if the "#content" overgrow, it must push the "#footer" to just below it.    http://i.imgur.com/WJmBD.png

Comment: I have updated my demo. The footer now always sticks to the bottom of the screen unless the content pushes it down.

Answer (score -1):

Use CSS's `position:fixed;` on the element with bottom and left set. e.g.:

```
#footer {
position: fixed;
bottom: 0px;
left: 0px;
}
```

Comment: Daedalus - it doesn't. "fixed" places the content relative to the viewport--not the block above it--as the OP is concerned.